# Simple Ember.js Relationships

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

I'm new to ember.js and I'm struggling a bit with setting up relationships between Ember Data Objects. Sorry I haven't done my google-due-diligance - I'm still so new to it that I don't even know what to search for.

I was able to get some of the basics down using coffee script and a bunch of tutorials, but now I'm struggling on some simple relationships,  What I want is to have multiple groups (cohorts), which have multiple people (boots), which have multiple tasks, which have a description are either completed or finished.  It's all one-to-many relationships for now - I'm not worried about many-to-many relationships at this point.

Unfortunately I'm getting tripped up in the very beginning.  All of my code is copy and paste-able.  I believe I have to somehow dynamically create a controller for the boots based off of which cohort is selected - or maybe I need to make a route and have it set up the controller?  I'm sure it's simpler than not but I just can't seem to find much resources online with my limited ember-vocabulary

```
Plato.Router.map ->
  this.resource('cohorts', ->
    this.resource('cohort', {path: ':cohort_id'}))

Plato.CohortsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  model: ->
    Plato.Cohort.find()
)

Plato.CohortsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()

Plato.BootsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()

Plato.Cohort = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  boots: DS.hasMany('Plato.Boot')
)

Plato.Boot = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr("string")
  cohort: DS.belongsTo('Plato.Cohort')
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code so far seams to be correct. But since you didn't provide any more details I've tryed to reproduce your situation **(providing the missing parts)** and here the [working results](http://jsbin.com/ovubej/2/edit) as a jsbin.
Please try to compare your code with the one in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovubej/2/edit) maybe you can find out what's not working for you.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well... I don't know what I was doing wrong, I could have sworn I tried exactly that but regardless it's working now!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this straightforward answer @intuitivepixel! I found I have a slightly different use case, which requires the relationship to only be stored on one side (i.e. Boots store which Cohort they belong to, but Cohorts store nothing about Boots). I took your solution and created [this modification](http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/f2c2V/) following my use case. I'm posting it here in case anyone else stumbles upon this answer and needs it =)